# Are some infinities really bigger than others?

Tags: infinity

I'm not a mathematician, but I recently read a thread about how some infinities are bigger than others. The argument put forward was that of mapping pairs of numbers from reals to naturals. There is also the argument of:

```
How many numbers are there between and including 1 and 2? 
An infinite set.

How many different numbers are there between and including 1 and 3?
An infinite set.

Since the number 3 cannot be counted in the set between 1 and 2, 
the infinite set which includes the numbers between and including 1 and 3 
must be a greater infinity than the set of numbers between and including 1 and 2.
```

I don't disagree with any of this. The way this is defined with cardinality of sets and whatnot, I can see how some "infinite" sets have more items than another.

But I think this is a bit of a linguistic trick. Maybe it's because we don't have enough words to express this concept or the existing words aren't specialized enough.

Isn't area/volume a better way of thinking about this? When someone says "one infinity is larger than another", then I believe most people "larger" consider larger to be referring to size.

That is, the set of reals may have a larger cardinality than the set of naturals, but the total "size" of their infinities are the same.

For example, let's say a girl and a boy are each given two apples. The boy cuts his apple in half, such that he now has "3 pieces of apples". I do not consider his share of apples to be larger than the girl's. I'm not sure why mathematicians are using cardinality rather than total size when saying "one infinity is larger than another". I think it would be better to say "some sets have a larger cardinality than others". You could say he has more pieces of apple, sure, but they both have the same volume of total apple.

I believe this is akin to what people are doing with numbers. Just because you split the number up further doesn't mean you actually have any more numbers. The size (total area, or volume, or whatever) of your set is still the same.

Similarly, pi is not "infinite". It's between 2 and 4.

And is infinity even infinitely large? Couldn't you argue it itself has a limit to its size? If what we're concerned with is area/total volume, then perhaps even infinity has a limit? I suppose it would depend on whether or not the universe is finitely sized. If it is, then the total volume that could be expressed in reality (not on paper) would be bounded by the volume of the universe.

We could use smaller units, but eventually are we not bounded by planck length being the smallest unit we could use? So the most we would be able to express would be `(volume of the universe in cubic meters) / (planck length in meters)`, [which is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28volume%20of%20the%20universe%20in%20cubic%20meters%29%20%2F%20%28planck%20length%20in%20meters%29) `2.2×10^115 m^2 (square meters)` in size?

**Edit:** Okay, I thought of a better way of phrasing this. There are multiple definitions of size. For example, you could be referring to cardinality, or maybe total area. This is why I believe the statement "some infinities are bigger than others" is *wrong*. Because if "bigger" in this context was referring to "volume", then it is not the case. The statement itself is too general and requires qualifiers (such as explicitly denoting that we're referring to cardinality) to be accurate. I think this is why it sounds more profound than it actually is (because the statement is fallaciously implying some infinities are larger than others in the general sense, and not just in the cardinal sense)

Cardinality is a subset of the concept of size. I believe this is why laypeople like myself often have difficulty accepting this statement (some infinities are larger than others), because it's assuming that we are referring to cardinality (which most people don't have that as their default interpretation of size). I would argue the more common interpretation is that of volume (as in my apple example, where no one would argue the boy has a bigger share of apple than the girl).

It is now common to hear people just throw out "some infinities are larger than others" in the general sense (just look at how many popular YouTube videos exclaim just this without any other qualifiers). Then when lay-people contest it the claimant retreat back to "oh, I just mean that some sets have a larger cardinality than others". Oh, well now it is much less profound/interesting and more-agreeable and boring. It seems like a mathematical motte-and-bailey!

Comment: I don't know what you mean, and that's why set theory exists.

Comment: Well, the mathematicians answer is still: yes some infinities are larger than others, in the sense of injective and/or surjective map. What you make out of it when you relate any of these concepts to reality will be of course of great debate and highly subjective. In any case, I think it is much much more and deeper than simply "linguistics".

Comment: I think you're confusing the notions of *measure* of a set and of cardinalty of this  set. The intervals $[1,2]$ and $[1,3]$ have the same cardinality, which is the cardinality of $\mathbf R$, but not the same measure. Similarly the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ has a smaller cardinality (they're countable) and has measure $0$.

Comment: Mathematicians are able to cut said apple in to a handful of pieces and recombine these pieces into two original-sized copies of the original apple - now what?

Comment: "Oh, well now it is much less profound/interesting and more-agreeable and boring." Now that I'm understanding your question better, I don't think it's really a question about math - yeah, the singular notion of "infinities" is often used in a sensationalist way, but take that as a reflection of popular media more than mathematics. I don't like it either, since it feels dishonest to put together words and then argue they mean something they don't usually mean (especially when math is full of surprising things that mean exactly what they mean)... but that's not at all specific to math.

Comment: @RyanPeschel I think you are a bit quick here. I don't think that the cardinality definition and the fact that there is always a bigger cardinality is not at all boring nor not-profound. And also when it comes to "volume" things can become very involved. For example one can define something like a volume in a fractional dimension (see for example [this triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle): the volume is infinite when consider as 1 dimensional object and has zero volume when consider as a 2 dimensional object, yet for some fractional dimension it has finite volume.)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians use *many* definitions of size, and it's specious reasoning to suppose that there's only one way to measure size.

In terms of cardinality, $[1,2]$ and $[1,3]$ are exactly the same, since $f(x):=2x-1$ is a bijection from the first to second. It says that as sets, the two have equivalent cardinality. This is useful if you're asking which set has more/less singleton elements.

In terms of length, $[1,3]$ is longer than $[1,2]$ in the sense of *measure*. However, size and measure are not always intuitively related, as can be seen for example by studying [Cantor sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

There are also comparative versions of infinity based on finite "filtrations," for example, the ratio of lengths of the family of sets $[1,x]$ and $[1,x^2]$ as: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^2}{x}=\infty$ despite both numerator and denominator tending to infinity.

Comment: I suppose this is where the confusion lies and why many lay-people such as myself have difficulty accepting it. When I hear "this infinity is bigger than this other one", I interpret that the way size and bigness is generally interpreted in English (total volume). Like with my apple example, the boy still has the same amount of apple as the girl. Mathematicians mean that the one set has a greater cardinality, which I consider to be a linguistic trick of some sort. The set isn't actually bigger, it just has a larger cardinality. Their total sizes are the same.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Take the interval $[0,1]$ and lets say it has a volume of $1$ (or length, whatever you want to call it). Now, I take a way the point $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the length of that interval now? Is it actually less then $1$? Does this one point matter? Now lets suppose I take all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ away. Then I will still argue that the volume hasn't changed. And this is of course confusing, because imaging what the interval $[0,1]$ really should be is impossible. So I really don't think your apple example helps to much.

Comment: @RyanPeschel: The problem with lay-mathematics is it tends to fall apart in corner cases. This is why mathematics uses many different rigorous definitions of "size." A classic example would be the Banach Tarski paradox, where the boy can mathematically cut his apple in such a way as to end up with 2 apples: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Tarski_paradox"

Comment: Yeah, I'm fine with the rigorous definitions. My contention is with people saying "some infinities are larger than others", because I don't think it's true in the general sense (because it's not true for area, only for cardinality). The statement requires more qualifiers to be true.

Answer (score 1):

No general definition of the "size" of a set, or of two sets being "equal in size", has gained much traction, except the one using cardinalities. If you can suggest an alternative equivalence relation with a nice ordering of its equivalence classes to serve the purpose, we can discuss it.

In some narrow contexts you can use something different. For example, all countable sets of real numbers, and also some uncountable ones, have zero "measure", while still others may have positive, infinite or undefined measure. But in general, there's no more benefit to characterising a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ as being "the same size" as one of cardinality $\aleph_0$ than to try the same thing with $2^5$ vs $5$.

> Maybe it's because we don't have enough words to express this concept or the existing words aren't specialized enough.

Just the opposite. When our terminology was less specialised, we just lumped together "infinite" sets. Now, however, we can be much more specific about their sizes.